# Are my MySql stats right?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on my website locally and I think that my MySQL stats are way to high. How do I know for sure that these stats are okay or they are off the roof?

My percentage of CPU usage on my computer is way too high as well. MySQL is using 53.5%. I want to know what I can do to make the performance of my website better.

This is a picture of my MySQL stats:

[image]

Comment: You have 8000 queries per second, that's on the upper end of a normal 1 cpu server, so high load is expected. If 8000 qps sound reasonable, because you have e.g. 500-1000 active users on your page (or your website's functionality simply requires a lot of small queries per user per second), probably all you can do to make it faster is buy more ram or a faster cpu or an ssd (or host it somewhere where you can scale or use load balancing). If 8000 queries per second sound much for your site, you might have to optimize the code on your webpage to be more efficient to lower your load.

Comment: Thanks you very much Racil, I already solve the problem. We just to have a notification section on our site, that we're into an infinite loop. We manage to make it more efficient and drop it to 10QPS. A huge mistake for or Web group.